# Recursive async/await

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I have a function that is hitting the OneDrive API. This API paginates it's data by 200 items per page. So when a response has another page (identified when `@odata.nextLink` being in the response data), I'm looping through the pages.  This is working fine, but I'd rather not use an iterative loop. I think I should be able to recursively call my function, and concatenate the data, but I'm unsure how to do that without overwriting my data each time.

Here is my current code:

```
async getFiles(storage, auth) {
        let url = `${auth.meta.serviceEndpointUri}/drives/${storage.meta.driveId}/items/${storage.meta.id}/children`;
        let files = [];
        let nextLink;
        try {
            do {
                const request = {
                    url,
                    method:'get',
                    headers:{
                        Accept: 'application/json',
                        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + authorization.access_token
                    }
                }
                const result = await axios(request);

                if(!result || (result && result.status !== 200)) {
                    // throw error here
                }

                const values = _.get(result.data, 'value', []);
                nextLink = _.get(result.data, '@odata.nextLink');
                files = files.concat(values);
                if (nextLink) {
                    url = nextLink;
                }

            } while (nextLink);

            return files;
        } catch (err) {
            // throw error here
        }
    };
```

Is there a way I could change this to not use the loop anymore, but use use async/await and call `getFiles` recursively with the new page url, while still concatenating `files` each time?

Comment: Is there a reason you want recursion? JavaScript has better performance using iterative loops vs recursive ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it'd be a relatively straightforward transformation. Make a separate function to carry out the recursive logic.

```
const getAllFiles = async (storage, auth) => {
    const url = `${auth.meta.serviceEndpointUri}/drives/${storage.meta.driveId}/items/${storage.meta.id}/children`;
    try {
        return await getFiles(url);
    } catch (err) {
        // handle error here
        // if you only want to re-throw, omit the try/catch entirely
    }
};

const getFiles = async (url, files = []) => {
    const request = {
        url,
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + authorization.access_token
        }
    };
    const result = await axios(request);

    if (!result || (result && result.status !== 200)) {
        // throw error here
    }

    const values = _.get(result.data, 'value', []);
    nextLink = _.get(result.data, '@odata.nextLink');
    files.push(values);
    if (nextLink) {
        getFiles(nextLink, files)
    }
    return files;
}
```

You might wish to omit the `catch` in `getAllFiles` entirely and let the error percolate up to the caller instead.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you. I guess it was defining the files array in the getFiles parameters that I wasn't thinking of. Thanks again!